# Mostrar información en un Div con consulta PHP y AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy creando un pequeño aplicativo web y me gustaría que una consulta hecha con AJAX se me cargue en un div. De momento el código que tengo es el siguiente:

La funcion javascript:

```
function printTorn(dataTorn){
    let parametres = {
        oper : "printTorn",
        data : dataTorn
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: parametres,
        url: 'php/ctrl/Calendar.php',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response){
            $(#contenedor).response;
            }   
    });
}
```

Dentro del archivo `index.php` tengo el div `<div id="contenedor"></div>` que es donde me gustaria mostrar el resultado de la consulta con ajax.
El archivo Calendar.php donde ejecuto la consulta tiene el código siguiente:

```
case 'printTorn':
            global $dataTorns;
            $dataY = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['dataTorn']));
            $db = DBWrap::get_instance();
            $db->Execute('select from aixada_torns where dataTorn=:q1', $dataY);?>
            <table><tr><th><h1>Torn <?php echo $dataTorn?></h1></th></tr><tr><th>UF:</th><th>Unitat familiar</th></tr><?php
            while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){
                $ufTemp = $row['ufTorn'];
                $rsUf = $db->Execute('select name from aixada_uf where id=:1q', $ufTemp);
                $results = $rsUf -> fetch_all();
                foreach($results as $result) {
                    echo "<tr><th>".$row['ufTorn']."</th><th>".$result -> name."</th></tr>";
                }
            }?>
            </table><?php
            console.log("Response: "+response);
            exit;
```

Pero no hay forma de que funcione. Con el depurador del navegador el mensaje que me aparece es `"Internal Server Error"...`

Comment: Hola, el **"Internal Server Error"** es que tu archivo **Calendar.php** tiene un problema, activa los errores en php y ve

Comment: Primero quita **<?php console.log("Response: "+response);** de tu php y mételo en javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya te dijeron en comentarios, primero quita de PHP  la línea `console.log("Response: "+response);` porque ese comando es de Javascript.

También te recomiendo organizar mejor tu código para que sea más legible y puedes identificar donde comienza y termina cada bloque, tanto PHP como HTML.

```
case 'printTorn':
        global $dataTorns;
        $dataY = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['dataTorn']));
        $db = DBWrap::get_instance();
        $db->Execute('select from aixada_torns where dataTorn=:q1', $dataY);
?>
        <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><h1>Torn <?php echo $dataTorn?></h1></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>UF:</th><th>Unitat familiar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
        while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){
            $ufTemp = $row['ufTorn'];
            $rsUf = $db->Execute('select name from aixada_uf where id=:1q', $ufTemp);
            $results = $rsUf -> fetch_all();
            foreach($results as $result) {
                echo "<tr><th>".$row['ufTorn']."</th><th>".$result -> name."</th></tr>";
            }
        }
?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
<?php
        exit;
```

Una vez corregido el error en PHP, estás usando jQuery y, para remplazar el contenido de un elemento, debes usar el método [$(elemento).html(nuevoContenido)](https://api.jquery.com/html/) en lugar de `$(elemento).response`:

```
function printTorn(dataTorn) {
    let parametres = {
        oper : "printTorn",
        data : dataTorn
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: parametres,
        url: 'php/ctrl/Calendar.php',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
            // Si quieres ver la respuesta en consola del navegador, debes mostrarla aquí:
            console.log('Respuesta: ' + response);
            // El ID del elemento debe estar entre comillas
            $('#contenedor').html(response);
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Tenia un error en el archivo php... Ya funciona perfectamente!